# Closing one div when opening another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

(first time poster)

As my name says I'm a noob when it comes to jquery so this is my problem, I got these 3 boxes that I can "open" and "close" BUT when I open one I want the other boxes to close... I have searched for an answer but couldn't really find one so if you know if this question has been answered then say so and post a link :)

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');

  if (clicks) {
    //odd click
    $(this).animate({
      height: '3rem'
    }, 500);

  } else {
    //even click
    $(this).animate({
      height: '13rem'
    }, 500);

  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);


});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: #be6666;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inside {
  height: 0rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  background-color: #be6666;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="margin-left:1rem;margin-right:1rem">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your are going to love that nick in a few years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `animate` method provided by `jQuery`, hovewer I would like to suggest you much simplier and better solution.

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('opened');
  $('.box').not(this).removeClass('opened');
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: #be6666;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.inside {
  height: 0rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  background-color: #be6666;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
}
.opened {
  height: 13rem;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="margin-left:1rem;margin-right:1rem">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Noob Look at my javascript code and then look at the others code. Do you see the difference? There's 4 lines of code in my solution versus 10+ in others. Keep on mind that you should always try to develop as light code as it is possible. Keep it slim and fit. Reconsider changing the best answer.

Comment: I like this approach for its simplicity, but believe there might be a bug here.  In the original post, an expanded box could be closed by clicking on it.  This bit of functionality has not been preserved.

Comment: @kind user it's not that you code is bad it's just that you can't press the same box again to close it...

Comment: @Noob Fixed it. ;) Enjoy.

Comment: @Noob Keep it slim! Take care.

Answer (score 3):

When expanding a box, iterate through all boxes and collapse the other ones.  This can be achieved using `$('.box').each`.  A reference to the expanding box is saved outside of the callback function and compared to each of the iterated boxes.  You can use this reference to determine which one not to collapse.

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');

  if (clicks) {
    //odd click
    $(this).animate({
      height: '3rem'
    }, 500);

  } else {
    //even click
    $(this).animate({
      height: '13rem'
    }, 500);

    // close any open boxes other than the expanding on
    var box = this;
    $('.box').each(function(index, element) {
      if (box != element) {
        $(element).animate({
          height: '3rem'
        }, 500);
        $(element).data("clicks", 0);
      }
    });
  }

  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: #be6666;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inside {
  height: 0rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  background-color: #be6666;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="margin-left:1rem;margin-right:1rem">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT** I'm not sure that this is totally Kosher, but I liked @Kind user's CSS-based approach and came up with another solution.  This approach keeps the code "lean and mean" but also preserves the "click-to-close" functionality.

Anyways, props to @Kind user.

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  
  // toggle open/close
  if ($(this).is(".opened")) {
    $(this).removeClass("opened")
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("opened")
    
    // close others
    var box = this;
    $('.box')
      .filter(function(index, element) {
        return element != box;
      })
      .removeClass("opened");
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: #be6666;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.inside {
  height: 0rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  background-color: #be6666;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
}
.opened {
  height: 13rem;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="margin-left:1rem;margin-right:1rem">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for props. I have upvoted your answer. And by the way, I've fixed issue with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can store a state info as attribute to select it to open/close. jQuery allows selection by attribute and run functions for each selected element automatically.

```js
function openOrClose(o, open) {
  o.animate({
    height: open ? '13rem' : '3rem'
  }, 500);  
  o.attr('data-state', open ? 'open' : 'closed');
}

$('.box').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr('data-state') != 'open') {
    // a click on a closed box
    
    // close the open boxes
    openOrClose($('.box[data-state=open]'), false);
    
    // open 'this'
    openOrClose($(this), true);
  }else{
    // a click on an already open box
    // so close it
    openOrClose($(this), false);
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 10rem;
  background-color: #be6666;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inside {
  height: 0rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  background-color: #be6666;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="margin-left:1rem;margin-right:1rem">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum iusto consequatur, tempora veritatis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First question, several good answers! Welcome to stackoverflow ;)